# jQuery Ajax request from local filesystem (Windows file:///)

Tags: jquery, localhost, wamp, wampserver

I'm trying to do an ajax request to get the contents of `"http://localhost/"` running on Windows Wamp Server.

The script is running from something like this:

`file:///C:/my/path/index.html`

I'm just using a standard $.ajax request to try and get the contents of localhost:

```
$.ajax({
          type: 'GET', 
          url: 'http://localhost/',
          success: function(data) {
            alert('success');
          }, error: function (data) {
            alert('failed');
          }
    });
```

I can't get it to be successful though... Seems to be some problem with the local filesystem or something. I'm not too sure.

Comment: Try just `/` for the url, then try `/index.html`

Comment: Can you access the url directly? Do you get an error in the js console?

Comment: @adam - Yes, accessing the url directly is fine. I get this error `Uncaught TypeError: Property 'responseText' of object #<Object> is not a function` I also get this error when trying the http:// `XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost/. Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.`

Comment: @Emmanuel The second one is the error Chrome gives when you try an AJAX request from a `file:///` URL.

Comment: @lonesomeday - Yes, with a bit more googling I found the answer is to set a Access-Control-Allow-Origin header. See my post below...

Comment: @Emmanuel.  To clarify, the error message you got is not the Chrome issue; Chrome issues a warning, but not the "cannot load" error.  Chrome's message will start with "Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL"

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Problem Solved!

I just had to add this header to my index.php file for http://localhost/

`header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');`

Thanks for your help anyhow guys!

Comment: Hi Emmanual, I'm in the same situation as u are. But I don't have any server codes, I've used a database proxy server dbmojo [link](code.google.com/p/dbmojo/). My scripts are located in local file:// directory. Now how can I put header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'); ? or is there any other solution?

Comment: @iEamin I'm not sure exactly of your situation... perhaps the header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" could be added via your apache (.htaccess) or other server config files? I'm not sure. I don't know of another way of doing cross-server/protocol requests like this.

Answer (score 11):

You say that the script is running from a `file:///` URL.  It's best not to do AJAX requests from `file` URLs, because they are treated inconsistently.  Chrome, for example, entirely disallows them.

However, your bigger problem here is the same-origin policy: you can only make AJAX requests to the same host as the web page itself.  `file:///` and `http://localhost` are **not** the same host (even if they are the same machine).

It's best to run everything off `http://localhost`.

Comment: Unforunately I think you're right :(. Probably good for security, but bad in my circumstances.

Answer (score 3):

This probably won't work, as the browser will think this is a cross-domain request. You've accessed the file via a file:// URL, but are trying to retrieve data from http://localhost. Try accessing your original file from http://localhost as well, and it'll probably start to work.

Comment: Yes, accessing it from http://localhost is fine. But basically what I'm trying to do with the file:/// script is to detect if wampserver is running by sending an ajax request and examining the results.

Comment: @Emmanuel - your code above shows you using the url, but here you say you are using the file path. Which is it?

Comment: @adam - the ajax request is running from file:///etc... and trying to get the contents of url `http://:localhost/`. Anyhow, see below for the my answer...