# Javascript/Html5 Project - some questions

Tags: php, javascript, html, ide

I am thinking of getting into JS/Html5 to do some web applications.

At the moment I am using Visual Studio Express 2010 (I am coming from a c#/silverlight/mssql background). Its nice. However, if I am doing html5/js I would prefer to write server side database lookup scripts in php for mysql, rather than mssql. VS does not cater for php mysql (as far as I know).

What ide is best for this? Do I need to install wamp server or somthing like that? (It needs to be free, this is just a hobby.)

Also, for non-database applications, eg simple games, how could I make my js/html5 app into as close as a downloadable app as possible? Is it possible? Downloading and unzipping a zip file is fine, if that has to be done.

The last thing I might need to know is how to save a text file to the hard drive. I think it can be done using Internet Explorer, but could you create a html page on the fly, with a copy button, which you could then instruct the user to paste into notepad, or somthing like that?

Comment: You don't need to use a PHP/mySQL backend, there are plenty of alternatives. As for html5/js games, they should be web games or you need some proper server-side programming (node.js) to make them desktop applications

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For IDEs, NetBeans is nice and simple, and works well for web stuff.  You don't really need an IDE though.  It won't be as helpful as it is in .NET.  Plenty of web developers use simpler text editors.  If you have a Mac I like TextMate.

If you need to serve files from a web server you will need a web server, but for most things you can develop just via the file system and file:// urls.  You will run into problems if you're trying to do AJAX - see [jQuery Ajax request from local filesystem (Windows file:///)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5469440/jquery-ajax-request-from-local-filesystem-windows-file)

Downloadable apps can be pretty much implemented with the HTML5 Offline Application spec.  See http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/offline.html for the formal stuff, but there are lots of examples, e.g. http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/appcache/beginner/.

As far as saving a text file, for security reasons I don't think that regular cross-platform JavaScript will let you do this. It's easy to do if you have a web server and you're serving up files and services for AJAX calls though.