# Unable to compile bootstrap less files using less.js

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, less

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Scipy Central</title>
    <link href="./less/bootstrap.less" rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css">
    <script src="./js/less-1.3.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
```

This is how my HTML page starts with.. However, I don't see that bootstrap is loading in the page!

The below is the error I find in the console.

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///D:/proj/less/bootstrap.less. Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP. less-1.3.3.min.js:8 Uncaught Error: NETWORK_ERR: XMLHttpRequest Exception 101
```

How to fix these issues?

**update**

Its working on Firefox (very slow). 
I am opening it with file:/// not Http

Comment: Do you run this page on a Web server, or you just open `file:///` URL ? Looks like less.js AJAX request failed, as no one serves a proper response.

Comment: @lxgreen file:/// and its working on firefox..

Comment: look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5469440/jquery-ajax-request-from-local-filesystem-windows-file . It says, Chrome disallows file:/// AJAX requests. I suggest you to run it over Web server.