# React + Crossdomain issues

Tags: reactjs, cross-domain

I am trying to render several components - but my service is a from a lamp stack. -- after rendering the component I try and do an ajax call -- I can see the call comes back in the network console -- but the alert is never triggered -- I've tried the ajax approach as well.

```
componentDidMount() {
    $.getJSON("http://localhost/react4/sample.json?callback=?", function(result){
       //response data are now in the result variable
       alert(result);
    });
}
```

//sample.json

```
[{"date": "2nd Aug"}]
```

---

network packet screenshot -- call and response from localhost
[image]

success from network packet
[image]

localhost - lamp stack running -- dummy json coming through
[image]

code on reactjs -- getjson doing the callback

[image]

no console error - no alert
[image]

adding console flags
[image]

only check1 appears -- its as if the response never comes back
[image]

Comment: Error messages in your console?

Comment: To be sure: you are running a local LAMP stack to support using localhost, right?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery Ajax request from local filesystem (Windows file:///)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5469440/jquery-ajax-request-from-local-filesystem-windows-file)

Comment: -- I don't think its a duplicate of the localfile system @MatthewHerbst -- php wamp localhost is running.

Comment: @TimoSta -- added screenshots

Comment: @TimoSta no errors to speak of -- warnings due to unused variables -- but no errors...

Comment: @MatthewHerbst - alright well turning it from a .json to a .php and adding that header -- and echoing it out - yes that works as a regular json call - header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');

--- but why wasn't the jsonp callback working? Its a reactjs project that's why I wondered if the different port was causing another issue

Comment: @MatthewHerbst - so why did the jsonp method I had in place not work?

Comment: So, first off that the port is the domain of the server. React - or any other front-end framework, doesn't care what port you are running on. I'll be the first to admit that my knowledge of jsonp is limited. However, my first guess: are you sure your server actually supports jsonp? It might simply never be calling the callback function.

Comment: -- well the react is on a node localhost at "http://localhost:3000/" -- and the wamp is on localhost -- which I assume to be 8080 by standard? -- so its odd that I can see the call come back ok in the network console -- but its as if it doesn't get called back